# Python 3 MySQL Syntax Error with Select Parameter

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to execute the following via Flask's MySQLdb module:

```
cur.execute("SELECT post_id FROM tbl_post WHERE post_file_path = '%s'", (_filePath,))
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'static/uploads/adc67db4-7d23-4bf1-a7ef-7e34dbed246a.jpg''' at line 1"
```

The query works fine via the command line so I'm fairly certain it's something to do with the way I'm providing my string argument. What am I doing wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't quote the placeholder `%s`, it's done by the database driver. This should work:

```
cur.execute("SELECT post_id FROM tbl_post WHERE post_file_path = %s", (_filePath,))
```

Comment: Had seen some examples using quotes, but this works perfectly thanks!